# jquery append for only for data-row and after child class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add a remove-button to the newly created element and to that element only, since the first search row cannot be removed.

```
let searchRow =
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<div class="input-group first-row" data-row-value=' + rowCounter + '>' +
    '<input name="text_search" class="form-control text_search" type="text"' +
    ' placeholder="Text To Search" required>' +
    '<select class="columns-list form-control selected_column">' +
    '<option disabled selected="selected" value="temp">Please wait...</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
    '<a class="search-row-button add-row" href="">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</a>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>';

let removeButton =
    '<a class="search-row-button remove-row" href="">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</a>';
```

`$searchWrapper` is just a div container.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-row', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    rowCounter++;
    $searchWrapper.append(searchRow);
    if (rowCounter > 1) {
        $('[data-row-value="'+rowCounter+'"]').find('.add-row').after(removeButton);
    }
    injectToSelect();
    // reloadRowColumnListener();
});
```

I am guessing I am doing some sort of wrong jquery appending, since i'm not getting expected result nor error.

#### Expected result

Remove row would be appended to `.input-group-addon` of only the newly added row.

Comment: why not just `$(searchRow).find('.add-row').after(removeButton);` or just combine the html instead of defining them seperately

Comment: Simple approach would be combine the string templates and use css `:nth-of-type` rule to hide the first one

Comment: @Pete that would add `removeButton` to each existing row, moreover, it would add that `removeButton` compoundingly.

Comment: an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uv5s9zqw/11/